# how to use iterator in while loop statement in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, iterator, generator

Is it possible to use a generator or iterator in a while loop in Python? For example, something like:

```
i = iter(range(10))
while next(i):
    # your code
```

The point of this would be to build iteration into the while loop statement, making it similar to a for loop, with the difference being that you can now additional logic into the while statement:

```
i = iter(range(10))
while next(i) and {some other logic}:
    # your code
```

It then becomes a nice for loop/while loop hybrid.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: has to be a while-loop? `for x in i` would be the natural way.

Comment: I guess you would not try your idea on `it = itertools.count(); while next(it):`

Comment: can you give more context on your use case?

Comment: how would you access the value the iter returned since you dont store it you just take the item and evaluaate its boolean result so what would you do in the loop since you dont have access to the item returned from the iter?

Comment: What you need to elaborate is what should be a stopping factor of `while` loop. How about `it = iter([True, False, 1, 0, 1]); while next(it): print('1')` ? The answers given are simple, but what's your exact intention?

Comment: What if we wanted to keep this general though, which is why I didn't indicate a specific additional logic. The stopping factor here can just be assumed to be exceeding the last iteration to where the iterator throws an exception. @RomanPerekhrest

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In Python >= 3.8, you can do the following, using [assignment expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/):

```
i = iter(range(10))
while (x := next(i, None)) is not None and x < 5:
    print(x)
```

In Python < 3.8 you can use [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
from itertools import takewhile

i = iter(range(10))
for x in takewhile({some logic}, i):
    # do stuff
```

"Some logic" here would be a 1-arg callable receciving whatever `next(i)` yields:

```
for x in takewhile(lambda e: 5 > e, i):
    print(x)
0
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: The `None` param is important or else it will throw an `stopIteration` exception

Comment: What if the element in the collection or streams is a None?

Comment: @xing If you have `None` elements in your collection, then you want to do `next(i)` and then catch the `StopIteration` exception

Comment: @AlexeiAndreev You can just replace `None` by any sentinel object that will not occur in your iterator.

Answer (score 12):

There are two problems with `while next(i):`

1. Unlike a `for` loop, the `while` loop will not catch the `StopIteration` exception that is raised if there is no `next` value; you could use `next(i, None)` to return a "falsey" value in that case, but then the `while` loop will also stop whenever the iterator returns an actual falsey value
2. The value returned by `next` will be consumed and no longer available in the loop's body. (In Python 3.8+, that could be solved with an assignment expression, see other answer.)

Instead, you could use a `for` loop with [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile), testing the current element from the iterable, or just any other condition. This will loop until either the iterable is exhausted, or the condition evaluates to false.

```
from itertools import takewhile
i = iter(range(10))
r = 0
for x in takewhile(lambda x: r < 10, i):
    print("using", x)
    r += x
print("result", r)
```

Output:

```
using 0
...
using 4
result 10
```

Comment: Everything's getting downvoted.. this seems like a perfectly valid question/answer.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to arrange for your iterator to return a false-like value when it expires.  E.g., if we reverse the `range` so that it counts down to 0:

```
>>> i = iter(range(5, -1, -1))
>>> while val := next(i):
...     print('doing something here with value', val)
...
```

This will result in:

```
doing something here with value 5
doing something here with value 4
doing something here with value 3
doing something here with value 2
doing something here with value 1
```

Comment: But this consumes `next(i)`, and if you call it again in the loop body you miss one value. Maybe with Python 3.8 assignment expressions, though.

Comment: Sure, this would be a prefect place to use assignment expressions. It wasn't clear from the question that you care about the value of the iterator.

Comment: Updated the example to use an assignment expression.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = iter(range(10))

try:
    next(a)
    while True:
        print(next(a))
except StopIteration:
    print("Stop iteration")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

You can do

```
    a = iter(range(10))

    try:
        a.next()
        while True and {True or False logic}:
            print("Bonjour")
            a.next()
    except StopIteration:
        print("a.next() Stop iteration")
```

Comment: `while True and (True or False):`-- is this a joke?

Comment: @Chris_Rands No it's a substitute for his [some logic]

Comment: This is exactly what I don't want to do. I want to put the next in the while statement.

Comment: got it (not my dv), you should also use `next(a)` in py 3