# Equivalent implementation pandas itertuples

Tags: python, pandas, while-loop, equivalent

How can I convert datatyp: Series to Pandas

Data example:

```
numpy_data = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 1]])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=numpy_data, index=[1,2,3], columns=["column1", "column2"])
```

Here I get the pandas.core.frame.Pandas data type for every row:

```
for row in df.itertuples():   
    print(row)
    print(type(row))
```

But if I read a single row I get pandas.core.series.Series

```
print(type(df.iloc[1]))
```

How can I convert series.Series to frame.Pandas?

Comment: You could do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59092561/how-to-use-iterator-in-while-loop-statement-in-python But why though?

Comment: It would help if you included a small reproducible example. There's some good stuff at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples about writing good reproducible examples for pandas. I think it would also help a bit if you gave more context around what you're actually trying to do. Looping over a pandas dataframe is rarely the best way to do things.