# Appending chunks of CSV to Database with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, csv

I'm trying to improve some code and stop it throwing a warning/error once it's finished (due to the use of `next(iter)`.

I'm essentially creating a database engine, reading in a large CSV file in chunks, and appending the data here to a PostgreSQL database.

However once the while loop is finished, there's an error. I could probably add some error handling to suppress this, but wondering if there's a more efficient way to do this in general.

```
   # Create database engine
   engine = create_engine(# contains Postgres connection stuff)

   # Read in CSV
   iter = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv", iterator=True, chunksize=100000)

   df = next(iter)

   # Convert column to datetime
   df.date_col = pd.to_datetime(df.date_col)

   # Create table
   df.head(0).to_sql(name = "mytable", con = engine, if_exists='replace')

   # Add first chunk
   df.to_sql(name="mytable", con=engine, if_exists='append')

   # Add remaining CSV data to database table
   while True:
       df = next(iter)
       df.date_col = pd.to_datetime(df.date_col)
       df.to_sql(name="mytable", con=engine, if_exists='append')
```

Comment: there is an error? What error? Can you please include the traceback? Is it `StopIteration` Error?

Comment: Thank you. Not sure why I didn't think of a for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is usage of `while(True)` loop. Ideally to iterate an iterator, you can use a `for` loop.

Incase you want to use a `while` loop, then take a look at [how to use iterator in while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59092561/how-to-use-iterator-in-while-loop-statement-in-python).

I would achieve what you are looking for using something like this:

```
_iter = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv", iterator=True, chunksize=100000)

df = next(_iter)

# Convert column to datetime
df.date_col = pd.to_datetime(df.date_col)

# Create table
df.head(0).to_sql(name = "mytable", con = engine, if_exists='replace')

# Add first chunk
df.to_sql(name="mytable", con=engine, if_exists='append')

for i in _iter:
    i.date_col = pd.to_datetime(i.date_col)
    i.to_sql(name="mytable", con=engine, if_exists='append')
```

Using a `for` loop avoids running into `StopIteration` exception which indicates end of an iterator. [Read More on Iterators here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-iterator-iterable-and-iteration).