# Python reading files in chunks

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large csv 20 gb file that i want to read to DataFrame.
I am using the following code

```
import pyodbc
import sqlalchemy
import pandas
chunks in pd.read_csv("test.csv", chunksize = 1000):
       print(list(chunks))
```

i am able to execute it without any memory issue but i want to unite to chunks to a single unit so that i can transfer the file to Postgres. I have created the engine for Postgres using `Sqlalchemy engine`.

I am new to python.
Please suggest how to loop and write the chunks to database. I read somewhere that generators are also a good option. TIA.

Comment: not familiar with SQL myself, but does this post help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/70794118/17270192

Comment: @Omniswitcher Thank you, this looks like a good approach. I ll try it out right away.

Comment: I am quite curious, did it work out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Appending chunks of CSV to Database with Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70794118/appending-chunks-of-csv-to-database-with-pandas)